# How to move a window from one group on taskbar to another?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp

I want to make a new group for windows in Windows XP taskbar. I would like to move windows from one group to another, how can I do this?

Here is image of one group which has 7 windows:

[image]

What I want to do is move out some windows into its own group.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not officially supported in XP.  The grouping is controlled by the OS based on the executable of each running process.  Multiple instances of the same executable are grouped together.  There is no option to change that behavior, only to enable/disable it in the Control Panel settings.  If you want to manipulate groups, you have to do so manually using the Toolbar API and undocumented data structures, as outlined in this article: [Manipulating Taskbar Buttons](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2006/10/01/manipulating-taskbar-buttons/) (use at your own risk).

The feature you are looking for is officially supported in Windows 7 and later by using **[Application User Model IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459.aspx)** instead.  Windows that are assigned the same AppUserModelID are grouped together. Use [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422.aspx) to set a process-wide AppUserModelID.  If an app (like a legacy app) does not assign a process-wide AppUserModelID, the OS auto-generates one.  The process AppUserModelID is used as the default when creating windows.  A window-specific AppUserModelID can then be assigned using [SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378430.aspx) and [IPropertyStore::SetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761475.aspx) if needed. This allows a single process to have multiple taskbar groups, and multiple related processes to use a single shared taskbar group.

Comment: Ah interesting. But can we like setup a shortcut and add command line options to that, then would it be seperate? google chrome manages to do something like this when you make new users/profiles

Comment: I don't use Chrome, so I have no clue what you are seeing it do.

Comment: Hey man this guys saying it might be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069413/is-it-possible-on-windows-xp-to-force-a-separate-taskbar-group-to-each-firefox-i

Comment: This is the article he linked but it confuses me so much: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2006/10/01/manipulating-taskbar-buttons/

Comment: That article does contain the info you would need to perform manual grouping/ungrouping, and seems fairly straight forward as long as you are careful with it. What is confusing about it?

Comment: Well I do it in js-ctypes in firefox-addon. If I have an example that does exactly what I need I can convert it slowly, but when I don't have an example that does exactly what I need I have a very hard time :( I've been working on it for awhile and got this far: [GitHubGist :: yajd / _ff-addon-snippet-GetTaskmanWindowCTypes.js](https://gist.github.com/yajd/e49b49b4d5c3887889b9)

Comment: Would you be able to knock up an example in any language that does what I need please? if possible please that would be so great than i can just convert :)

Comment: What is wrong with using the examples that are in the article itself? It shows you how to do each step. It is up to you to decide how to apply the steps to your app's logic.

Comment: I studied hard man for like 5 days Im not so good at it though :( Would it be possible for you to write something that takes a group of notepad windows (10 windows) and seperates 1 of them from the gorup. Forgive me for asking this much man. Its for my firefox addon ["Profilist"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profilist/)

Comment: The place I'm stuck at is `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` I can't figure out what that's suppoed to be, I'm tring to use it in `SendMessage(hToolbar,TB_BUTTONCOUNT,0,0);` I figured out for `SendMessage` that `WM_SETICON` was `0x0080` but searching on MSDN but MSDN doesnt state what `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` is :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says that `WM_SETICON` is `0x0080` and I'm having hard time figureing out all the codes for the messages used in tha tutorial: `TB_GETBUTTON`, `TB_SETBUTTONINFO`, `TB_MOVEBUTTON`, `TB_GETIMAGELIST`, `TB_SETBUTTONINFO`, `TB_GETBUTTON`, `TB_BUTTONCOUNT`, `TB_GETBUTTONTEXT`.

Comment: Also in tutorial when he does `rez:=SendMessage(hToolbar, TB_GETBUTTON, ButtonIndex, integer(@aButton));` what does `integer(@aButton)` mean?

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787297.aspx) tells you that `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` is defined in `Commctrl.h`. If you have the Win32 SDK, look in that file and you will see `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` defined as `(WM_USER + 24)`, ie 1048 (0x0418). A simple Google search would have also found that for you. Same goes with the other messages (`TB_GETBUTTON` is 1047, `TB_SETBUTTONINFOA` is 1090, `TB_SETBUTTONINFOW` is 1088, `TB_MOVEBUTTON` is 1106, `TB_GETIMAGELIST` is 1073, `TB_GETBUTTONTEXTA` is 1069, `TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW` is 1099).

Comment: `integer(@aButton)` is taking the memory address of the `aButton` variable and type-casting that to an integer (the last parameter of `SendMessage()` is an `LPARAM`, which is a 32bit or 64bit integer depending on whether you are compiling for a 32bit or 64bit OS).

Comment: Ah header i had no idea thanks man!! I learned a ton here I think I can do this I'll report back with a solution :) thanks again man

Comment: Oh how did you open `Commctrl.h`? Where can i find that to look at what's in there? Thanks agian man

Comment: As I said earlier: "If you have the Win32 SDK...".  You can download it from MSDN, if you do not have a compiler that includes it.  Or just look for copies/translations of CommCtrl.h online.

Comment: [Here](https://emoacht.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/csharp-appusermodelid/) is a post showing a complete program for reading and writing shortcuts AppUserModelID. In case that blog dies, it also links to source code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nasherder/files/samplecode/ShellLinkPlus.zip/download). It works!